# В чем смысл текстовых шаблонов T4 и когда их имеет смысл использовать?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, t4

В чем смысл [текстовых шаблонов T4](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb126445(v=vs.110).aspx)? По сути, этого же можно добиться с помощью динамической компиляции. Доступ к исходному коду так же не даёт никаких преимуществ, так как править его не имеет смысла из за перегенерации.

Comment: Ничего не понял...

Comment: @Qwertiy: Судя по всему, это про T4.

Comment: Вот здесь ещё кое-что, вроде: https://habrahabr.ru/post/176097/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Если вы имеете в виду T4, то их смысл — встроенный в систему шаблонизатор/[DSL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA). T4 используется в двух вариантах: времени компиляции и времени выполнения.

T4 времени выполнения обычно используется как шаблонизатор, и означает, что вы можете легко генерировать текстовые файлы, в которых большая часть текста постоянна, а куски необходимо генерировать программно. Простой пример — шаблон письма, в который нужно вставить имя адресата, адрес и наименование товара.

Но гораздо более интересным является T4 времени разработки. Эта штука позволяет вам генерировать код на этапе компиляции (точнее, даже до неё). То есть, у вас появляется ещё одно прекрасное (хотя и немного неуклюжее — если не сравнивать с шаблонной магией Александреску) средство для настоящего метапрограммирования. Причём в отличие от решений, которые вы могли бы соорудить на коленке, T4 встроен в Visual Studio, и сгенерированные файлы просто видны в дереве Solution Explorer'а, и подхватываются компилятором.

T4 используется для кодогенерации многими проектами, начиная с [Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8583335/276994). [Вот здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2045773/276994) ещё достаточно впечатляющий список. Вот, например, пример того, как [автоматически генерировать определения Dependency Property](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35984/Generate-WPF-and-Silverlight-Dependency-Properties). (Я тоже использовал T4 для генерации из текстового представления XAML-словарей для локализации.)

---

Кодогенерация времени выполнения и правда не лучший метод использования T4. Для этих целей лучше подходит CodeDOM (или, кажется, Roslyn API). А для кодогенерации времени компиляции доступ к сгенерированным исходникам очень важен, например, для отладки.

---

Дополнение к вопросу из комментария. Да, можно в шаблоне генерировать другой шаблон.

Например, такой вот шаблон

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ output extension=".tt" #>

<# string open = "<" + "#" + "@", close = "#" + ">"; #>

<#= open #> template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" <#= close #>
<#= open #> assembly name="System.Core" <#= close #>
<#= open #> import namespace="System.Linq" <#= close #>
<#= open #> import namespace="System.Text" <#= close #>
<#= open #> import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" <#= close #>
<#= open #> output extension=".cs" <#= close #>

class Test
{
    public int i;
}
```

порождает подчинённый шаблон

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>

class Test
{
    public int i;
}
```

который в свою очередь порождает класс

```
class Test
{
    public int i;
}
```

Никаких специальных действий выполнять не нужно, просто добавьте шаблон T4 через Add → New item → Text Template (не Runtime Text Template!)

[image: добавляем, не стесняемся]

В T4-файл положите текст шаблона, как он представлен выше, и вы получите такую вот необычную структуру вашего solution'а:

[image: мы добавили шаблон в ваш шаблон, чтобы вы могли генерировать шаблоны пока вы генерируете шаблоны]

Comment: Небольшой вопрос: А как с помощью шаблона породить другой шаблон и добавить его в обозреватель решений? Это какое-то VS API использовать нужно?

Comment: @iluxa1810: Ну, я никогда не пробовал сгенерировать из шаблона другой шаблон, если честно. Но если генерировать .cs, то он автоматически возникает в проекте, ничего специального делать не нужно.

Comment: @iluxa1810: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: а из коробки VS не имеет средств для подсветки синтаксиса или автопродолжения при написании шаблона=> как я понимаю, шаблоны пишутся в файле кода, а потом копипастятся в шаблон файл?

Comment: @iluxa1810: Нет, из коробки нету. И пишу прямо в файле, никуда не копирую. Но это, наверное, не самый лучший путь.

Comment: И еще вопрос, а можно ли заблокировать генерацию, что бы имеющийся код не перегенерировался? Какой-нибудь LOCK поставить...

Comment: @iluxa1810: Если вы не трогаете код, то и рекомпиляции не будет. А если вы хотите просто поэкспериментировать, например, поменяйте `output extension` на `txt` временно.